# How To Sending List Object instead of Single Object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm trying serialize form and than sending values of both `<tr>` to controller action method and The action method accept the `List<CustomerContactInfo>`, but when serializing happening it will be just sending the value of first `<tr>` and not a `List` and than model returns `null`. Can anyone please help me or point me into the right direction :)

Form:

```
<form id="Myform">
    <table>
        <tbody id="output">
        <tr>
            <td>Addresse: <input type="text" name="Addresse[0]" value="Torv 2"></td>
            <td>City: <input type="text" name="City[0]" value="borg"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Addresse: <input type="text" name="Addresse[1]" value="Strand 1"></td>
            <td>City: <input type="text" name="City[1]" value="Slage"></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
    <button type="button" onclick="CreateUsers();">Create</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function CreateUsers() {

        var model = $("#Myform").serializeArray();
        var data = {};

        $(model).each(function (index, obj) {
            data[obj.name] = obj.value;
        });

        console.log(data);

        var settings = {

            "url": '@Url.Action("CreateMultiUsers", "User")',
            "method": "POST",
            "data": JSON.stringify(data),
            "dataType": "json",
            "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
        $.ajax(settings).done(function (re) {
            console.log(re);
        });
    }
</script>
```

console.log(data):

```
{Addresse[0]: "Torv 2"
Addresse[1]: "Strand 1"
City[0]: "borg"
City[1]: "Slage"}
```

Action:

```
    public class CustomerContactInfo
    {
        public string Addresse { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }  
    }


[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateMultiUsers(List<CustomerContactInfo> model)
        {
                //do something with model

               return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: why would it make a list? What do you mean? If you need two forms, use two forms?

Comment: What is `$` here? `jQuery`? Add it to your tags.

Comment: @zfrisch i dont need two forms , i just need to send value of my <tr> which is two. i also load contents of table dynamically

Comment: @spender i didnt understand , what should i add ?

Comment: There is no mention of `jquery` anywhere in your question, but `$` is not native JS. I assume that the `$` is jquery, but only you can tell us for sure. When I say "add it to your tags", at the moment, you have tags `javascript`, `c#` and `ajax`, but no `jquery`. This is where it should be added.

Comment: So you want `data = { contactInfo: [[Address, City], [Address, City]] }` ?

Comment: Stuff like serialsiation tends to only send arrays, not lists. The modifyability of lists only makes sense while it is in memory. If I wanted to modify it during transport, modifiying a array would be as easy to modify as a list. **If** I even wanted too. And converting between arrays and lists and vise versa is easy, as lists carry all the functions you need for both directions.

Comment: Yes, i just added :) is there any way help me with my Question @spender :)

Comment: @zfrisch Yes :)